# Miminum permissions required for cross domain Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership?

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory

**Forest 1**

Parent Domain A

|___Child Domain A

**Forest 2**

Parent Domain B

Two Way trust between Forest 1 Child Domain A and Forest 2 Parent Domain B

User is in Parent Domain B

Group is in Child Domain A

Credentials are in Child Domain A

`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity 'Parent Domain B User' -server 'Parent Domain B DC' -ResourceContextServer 'Child Domain A DC' -Credential 'Child Domain A User Creds'`

This returns the following error:

> Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An operations error occurred

I can't figure out which domain the credentials need to be in and what the minimum permissions needed are.

Comment: Please, separate your code and question text. This is very difficult to understand what your code is here.

Answer (score 0):

"An operations error occurred" usually indicates that some of the inputs you have given are wrong. It does not indicate a permissions issue.

I tried it in our environment since we do have a similar setup, and I was able to run the command without error.

For `'Parent Domain B User'` I used only the `sAMAccountName`, and for the two DC's, I used the DNS names of the domains. You should need to specify exact DCs - just the domain names.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity 'username' -server 'domain1.com' -ResourceContextServer 'domain2.com'
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. I use the same command against other Domains and it works with no issues. Its just when I look at these two specific domains the issue occurs.